# use php to get value of jquery div

Tags: php, jquery

I've a div `<div id="single-home-container"></div>` that displays a value from a jquery script. Can I use php to get that value so I can pass it into a mysql query?
Thanks

Comment: PHP is server side and you can't use it to directly get anything from the client side. You have write some client side code to send the data to PHP. If you using jQuery, you probably want to use something in the `$.ajax()` family.

Answer (score 1):

yes this is called [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29). There are all kinds of AJAX functions in jQuery, in your case I think post would work great. This is the standard example from the jQuery doc:

```
$.post('ajax/test.php', $('#single-home-container').html(), function(data) {
  $('.result').html(data);
});
```

Take a look [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/).

Comment: Thanks Florian. I then placed `$result = $_GET['result']; echo $result;` on my footer.php to see the results but to no avail. I changed the file path to /footer.php and also tried absolute URL but again to no avail. Any idea? Thanks

Comment: Note `$.post` in the comment. You should expect value to come from `$_POST` array, not `$_GET`.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that to to no avail.My code is as follows:
`
$(document).ready(function(){      
 $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});     
 $(".locationID").click(function(){         
  var post_id = $(this).attr("rel"); 
  //alert($(this).attr('rel'));
  $("#single-home-container").html("loading...");         
  $("#single-home-container").html(post_id);

  $.post('/footer.php', $('#single-home-container').html(),  function(data) { $('.result').html(data); });
  
  return false;    
 });  
}); 
`And on footer.php `$result = $_POST['result']; echo 'Result: '.$result;` nothing shows?

Comment: Could you write this into the question? I just can't read the code this way.

Answer (score 0):

You should **definitely** take some time to learn the concept of [AJAX](http://www.interaktonline.com/support/articles/Details/AJAX%3a+Asynchronously+Moving+Forward-How+does+AJAX+work?.html?id_art=36&id_asc=308) before trying to use it.